# ngRepeat and checkbox

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a div with ng-repeat:

```html
<div ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="this.value" ng-checked="false">{{fruit.code}} - {{fruit.short_name}}
</div>
```

Here furits is array object and which contains the field code, short_name.

```
furits: {
         {
          code : code_value1,
          short_name :short_name_value1
         },
         {
          code : code_value2,
          short_name :short_name_value2
         },...
         {
          code : code_value..,
          short_name :short_name_value..
         },
       }
```

I would like to get the code of checked checkbox after submit button click and insert those codes in new array.

And also send the same array to server to complete the task.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: please add here your web service to send array to server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="fruit.isSelected" />{{fruit.code}} - {{fruit.short_name}}
</div>
<input type="button" ng-click="sendServer()" value="Submit" />
```

And your controller methods are like ,

```
 $scope.sendServer = function(){
  $scope.checkedFruits = [];
  for(i = 0; i < $scope.fruits.length; ++i){
    if ($scope.fruits[i].isSelected)
        $scope.checkedFruits.push(fruit.code);
  }
  $scope.postData();
 }

//Send array to server via web service with parameter FruitsCode

 $scope.postData = function () {
   $http.post('http://your.webservice/', {FruitsCode:$scope.checkedFruits}).success(
    function(data){
        $scope.response = data
    })
```

}

Hopes this will help you !

Comment: thank you both. but, this line: "$scope.fruits[i].isSelected" returns "undefined"...

Comment: please change in view ng-model="fruit.isSelected"

Comment: please add isSelected field array object fruits with default false value

Comment: you right... i changed it to "fruit.isChecked" (that was it's wrote here). now it's working! thank you. what the different between the 2 options?

Comment: angular js has two way binding from controller to view and view to controller

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="fruit in fruits">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="fruit.isChecked" />{{fruit.code}} - {{fruit.short_name}}
</div>
<input type="button" ng-click="save()" value="SAVE" />
```

And inside your controller :

```
$scope.save = function(){
    var myFruits = [];
    for(i = 0; i < $scope.fruits.length; ++i){
        if ($scope.fruits[i]. isChecked)
            myFruits.push(fruit.code);
    }
}
```